# Bus Error:10 with strtok in C

Tags: c

Here is my code, when I running the code, always bus error 10:

```
void print_tokens(char *line)
{
    static char whitespace[] = " \t\f\r\v\n";
    char *token;

    for(token = strtok(line, whitespace);
       token != NULL;
       token = strtok(NULL, whitespace))
       printf("Next token is %s\n", token);
}

int main(void)
{
    char *line = "test test test";
    print_tokens(line);
    return 0;
}
```

Please help me!

Comment: [See also](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4480552/why-does-the-following-c-program-give-a-bus-error)

Comment: Also, Your code above is missing a `)` before the `;` on the `for()` line. (and quite possibly some `{`, `}`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`strtok` will modify the buffer it is passed; this is [contractual](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strtok):

> Be cautious when using these functions. If you do use them, note that:
>
> *
>   These functions modify their first argument.
>
> *
>   These functions cannot be used on constant strings.

When you declare a string as `char *str = "blah blah";` in C, you are declaring it to be read-only memory, so when you pass it to `strtok` the result is undefined since `strtok` wants to modify the buffer but can't since it's read-only.

To address this issue declare `str` as an array instead: `char str[] = "blah blah";`

Answer (score 5):

You cannot modify a string constant. Define `line` this way:

```
char line[] = "test test test";
```